# Symfony2 query not working

Tags: symfony

I am new to Symfony 2, I have a scenario where quiz E is made up of quiz A,B,C & D. These are stored as subQuizes of Quiz E. I am trying a query to find all the questions for all the sub quizes of quiz E, but it just returns the questions of quiz A. My Code:

```
$subQuizesString = '';
foreach($quiz - > getSubQuizes() as $key = > $quiz)
$subQuizesString. = $quiz - > getId().',';
$subQuizesString = rtrim($subQuizesString, ',');

$query = $em - > createQuery(
    'SELECT question
                    FROM CriticalReadingQuizBundle:Question question
                    WHERE question.quiz in (:quizes) AND question.active = true
                    ORDER BY question.orderIndex, question.quiz, question.id') - > setParameter('quizes', $subQuizesString);

$questions = $query - > getResult();
```

Firstly, I would like to do away with compiling the subQuizesString as I feel in Symfony2 this should be unnecesary (but I don't know how), and secondly (probably more importantly), I would like to know why I am only receiving the questions of the quiz A.

As always, your help is valuable and very appreciated.

Comment: Try to debug it a bit, for example looking on dev.log file the query that was executed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way:

```
$subQuizesArray = array();
foreach($quiz - > getSubQuizes() as $key = > $quiz) {
   $subQuizesArray[] = $quiz - > getId();
}

$query = $em - > createQuery(
    'SELECT question
                    FROM CriticalReadingQuizBundle:Question question
                    WHERE question.quiz IN :quizes AND question.active = true
                    ORDER BY question.orderIndex, question.quiz, question.id') - > setParameter('quizes', $subQuizesArray);

$questions = $query - > getResult();
```

Comment: This worked, thank you. Is there no way to get the subQuiz id's into an array without having to loop? Something like $quiz->getSubQuizes()->getId(). Obviously that doesn't work (I tried it, but something similar?

Comment: research doctrine hydration.